# How to formulate the symmetry in Ramsey's theorem for $c$ colours?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring, ramsey-theory, symmetric-functions

Ramsey's theorem for $c$ colours states that (this statement is not copied from anywhere):

> Let $c\ge 2$ be an integer, $[c]=\{1,2,\ldots,c\}$ represent $c$ colours, and let $(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_c)$ be a list of integers greater than or equal to $2$ (note: the integer $1$ can be allowed among the $r_i$ but I prefer to not include this degenerate case). For all sufficiently large positive integers $n$ and for any colouring of the complete graph $K_n$ by the colours $[c]$, there exists an index $i\in[c]$ such that this colouring of $K_n$ contains a monochromatic $i$-coloured $r_i$-clique.

The smallest such $n$ is denoted by $R(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_c)$. Now suppose the colours stayed the same but we swapped some $r_i$ and $r_j$ in the list $(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_c)$. Then the two Ramsey numbers stay the same by an argument involving inverse colourings. Since every permutation can be represented by a composition of transpositions, it does not matter how we order the $(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_c)$. A couple of questions related to each other that are on my mind are:

1. Okay... so the $r_i$ are independent of order. But if we put them into a multiset where repetition is allowed but order does not matter, then is each $r_i$ still related to a specific colour?
2. Is it true that the colour just need to be distinct once we pass the $(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_c)$ to a multiset, or does the order on the colours still matter?

These questions are inspired by the fact that when $r_1=r_2=\cdots=r_c$ have a common value $r$, then $R(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_c)$ has to do with the existence of a monochromatic $r$-clique without caring about the particular colours; the only thing that matters is the size of the desired clique and the number of acceptable distinct colours.

Basically, what I'm wondering is the extent to which we can do some "modding out" in Ramsey's theorem after the usual quoted theorem is obtained, either with respect to the $r_i$ or the colours themselves, or both. I just can't wrap my head around what is the possible statement of the symmetry that seems to exist.

Comment: 1. Yes, but it doesn't matter which color. 2. No, the colors don't come in any particular order. The colors form a set and the $r_i$ are a function on that set; you can also think of them as a multiset.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan To ensure that I understand you correctly: Firstly, in the ordinary Ramsey's theorem before any modding out, there is no order on the colours, so they form just a set. Secondly, they map to the positive integers (greater than or equal to $2$ if desired). And then to mod out, we can make the observation that, in another such multiset, if the preimage of each positive integer has the same cardinality as previously, then the "new" Ramsey number is equal to the old one?

Comment: Yes, but to me that's sort of an awkward way of talking about it. The point of distinguishing the set of colors and the numbers $r_i$ is just that the relevant symmetry here is the group of permutations of the set of colors.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I though you were saying that the fact that the colours don't need to be ordered (and so they can be permuted in any way or placed in a set) is already in the ordinary statement of Ramsey's theorem. After your first comment, I was thinking of additionally considering the symmetry in the fact that, as long as the number of each positive integer appears the same number of times, the Ramsey number stays the same. Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by "group of permutations of the set of colours."

Comment: That's not a new symmetry; if $\{ r_i \}$ and $\{ s_i \}$ are two sets of numbers such that each positive integer appears the same number of times then they are related to each other by some permutation of the set of colors. Maybe that's what you wanted to know?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think I understand now. Let's say we write out the colours left to right in a row in some order. Then we write the positive integers in a row above it. Then we draw an arrow from each colour to a positive integer to indicate the acceptable size of its clique. If we permute the colours but keep the sticks in the same place, then the Ramsey number stays the same. Is that what you are saying? I believe this is equivalent to the preimage formulation in my first comment?

Comment: That's true but it's not what I'm saying. You said this observation about multiplicities is an "additional" symmetry but it's not, it's already implied by the freedom we have to permute the colors arbitrarily. Here's a really concrete proof: by permuting the colors you can always arrange the $r_i$ to be in, say, weakly increasing order. If you also permute the $s_i$ to be in the same order then in order for their multiplicities to match they just have to be the same sequence.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan when you are permuting the colours in some way (and you are starting with some multiset where the colours map to the positive integers), are your multiplicities attached to the colours during the permutation, or are the multiplicities like in my previous comment (getting attached to some other colours)?

Comment: They're attached to the colors; that's the interpretation I intended.